# Cats Effect 3 Mutex unexpected behaviour

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I stumbled upon an unexpected `cats.effect.std.Mutex` behaviour (it doesn't work for a certain case). Looks like I missed some core understanding of `Async` but haven't found the root cause.

Imports:

```scala
import cats.{Applicative, FlatMap}
import cats.effect.std.{Console, Mutex}
import cats.effect.*
import cats.implicits.*
import cats.syntax.all.*

import scala.concurrent.duration.*
```

Suppose we have a service

**Working scenario**

```scala
  class Service[F[_] : Async : FlatMap : Console](mutex: Mutex[F]) {
    def run(name: String): F[Unit] =
      for
        _ ← Console[F].println(s"[$name] entered [run] within [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]")
        _ ← mutex.lock.surround {
          for {
            _ ← Console[F].println(s"[$name] entered [locked] within [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]")
            _ ← Async[F].sleep(2.seconds)
            _ ← Console[F].println(s"[$name] almost left [locked] within [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]")
          } yield ()
        }
        _ ← Console[F].println(s"[$name] left [run] within [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]")
      yield ()
  }
```

and a runner

```scala
object MutextTests extends IOApp:

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    (for
      mutex ← Mutex[IO]
      service ← IO.pure(Service(mutex))
      f1 ← service.run("Alice").start
      f2 ← service.run("Bob").start
      _ ← f1.join
      _ ← f2.join
    yield ()).as(ExitCode.Success)
```

with expected output

```
[Alice] entered [run] within [io-compute-2]
[Bob] entered [run] within [io-compute-2]
[Alice] entered [locked] within [io-compute-blocker-5]
[Alice] almost left [locked] within [io-compute-1]
[Bob] entered [locked] within [io-compute-blocker-3]
[Alice] left [run] within [io-compute-blocker-1]
[Bob] almost left [locked] within [io-compute-2]
[Bob] left [run] within [io-compute-blocker-2]
```

But if I replace `Console[F]` with `Async[F]` the mutex stops working:

**Not working scenario**

```scala
class Service[F[_]: Async : FlatMap : Console](mutex: Mutex[F]) {
  def run(name: String): F[Unit] =
    for
      _ ← Async[F].pure(println(s"[$name] entered [run] within [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]"))
      _ ← mutex.lock.surround {
        for {
          _ ← Async[F].pure(println(s"[$name] entered [locked] within [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]"))
          _ ← Async[F].sleep(2.seconds)
          _ ← Async[F].pure(println(s"[$name] almost left [locked] within [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]"))
        } yield ()
      }
      _ ← Async[F].pure(println(s"[$name] left [run] within [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]"))
    yield ()
}
```

with unexpected output

```
[Alice] entered [run] within [io-compute-1]
[Bob] entered [run] within [io-compute-1]
[Alice] entered [locked] within [io-compute-5]
[Bob] entered [locked] within [io-compute-4]
[Alice] almost left [locked] within [io-compute-5]
[Alice] left [run] within [io-compute-5]
[Bob] almost left [locked] within [io-compute-6]
[Bob] left [run] within [io-compute-6]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not the `Mutex`, but the use of `pure` + `println`.
You are printing before constructing the whole program to be passed to the `lock.surround`. Thus, giving the impression that both fibers acquired the `Mutex` at the same time; but actually both just tried to acquire it at the same time but only one got access to it.

To get back the expected behaviour you should use `delay` to suspend the `println` *(actually the right thing is `blocking`, and the best thing is to use `Console` or just `IO.println` directly)*.
You can see that is the case here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/szV1P8X5SeiEiYhzItPmRA/1

---

BTW a couple of notes:

1. `Async` + `FlatMap` is redundant, `Async` is already a `Monad`. I am actually not sure how that didn't cause you a compile error.
2. `cats.implicits.*` is deprecated, all you need is `cats.syntax.all.*`
3. Don't `start` and `join` fiber manually, is error-prone. Always prefer higher level combinators like `parTupled`.
4. Printing the current thread name on a **CE** app is usually not very helpful.

I have a couple of examples and resources to get familiarized with the whole *"programs as values"* paradigm here: https://github.com/BalmungSan/programs-as-values hope it can be helpful :D *(English recording in the process to be recovered)*.